# Can I publish my book in the Russian language with advertising and selling online?

Tags: publishing, translation, international, audiobook

I'm based in the USA.  I wrote a book in the Russian language.  My book had already been published in Russia - 500 paper copies.

Now I would like to republish my book in a digital format and as an audio book and list it for sale on a number of online stores, such as Ozon, B&N, Bookland, Amazon, Kobo, Apple, etc.

Is there some kind of agency that could help me accomplish this?  I don't need my book to be translated to any other language, at least for now.  Working with Russian agencies based in Russia is difficult due to the incompatibility of money transfer services.

Comment: I have repeatedly and successfully transferred money from Germany to Russia. You can directly transfer money from a US bank account to a Russian bank account in the same way you would transfer it inside the US or to any other country. If your partner has no bank account, you wouldn't want to deal with them anyway. If you still do, there are many other options of transferring money such as Western Union or PayPal.

Comment: Also, the process for self-publishing ebooks is not dependent on the book's language. Just google for instructions on how to create an ebook and get it listed in online stores, and that's it. You don't need an agency for that.

Comment: Can your publisher in Russia help? Can they help you find an American publisher?

Comment: Did you notice that in "the Russian language" and "in Russia" are wholly different things, please|?

Comment: Further to anything else, why have you not asked the cultural attache at the US Embassay in Moscow, please? Isn't he there largely to facilitaste projects like yours?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a ready market on Amazon US for eBooks published in Russian.

Search on www.amazon.com for "Russian Edition" (books in foreign languages are appended with a similar 'tag') and you will be presented with a list of 20,000+ books.

Here is the direct link to the that page: [https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=%22russian+edition%22](https://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=%22russian%20edition%22)

I would imagine that other eBook publishers have similar policies. With a growing global community of people with disparate language needs I fail to see why not.

Good luck with your publishing journey, my friend.